# Indecomposable comodules

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, bialgebras

For a Hopf algebra $A$, we say that a comodule $V$ is **indecomposable** if it is not equivalent to a direct sum of irreducible comodules.

$\bullet$  What is an example of a finite dimensional indecomposable comodule that is not irreducible?

$\bullet$ Every irreducible comodule of $A$ is isomorphic to a subcomodule of $A$, when we look at $A$ as a comodule over itself. What is an example of an indecomposable comodule that is not isomorphic to a subcomodule of $A$?

Comment: For finite-dimensional coalgebras $A$, there is an anti-equivalence between $A$-comodules and $A^*$-modules. So you can easily ask equivalent questions about $A^*$-modules, which are hopefully more familiar terrain. For example, there are representations of the cyclic group $C_p$ over a characteristic-$p$ field that are indecomposable but not irreducible.

Comment: @darij Will such comodules embed into the Hopf algebra $A$ or not?

Comment: Since everything is finite-dimensional, duality works. So embedding a comodule into $A$ is equivalent to writing its dual $A^*$-module as a quotient of $A^*$. Pretty sure there are some indecomposable $A^*$-modules that are not quotients of $A^*$ when $A$ is a mildly interesting group algebra over a finite field. Not sure I know one specifically.